# How to query only those model items where 'hasOne' relation instance is empty?

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

I have model instances with 'hasOne' relation.

Model A has Model B relation.

Some models A have actual instances in that relation and others don't.

How do I query the collection so that to get only those instances of model A that have no content in the B relation?

Comment: Do you mean [tag:loopbackjs] instead?

Comment: fixed the tag, thanks